# Ext Filter with special value

Tags: extjs, filter

I have a Model A (include Model B). For example:

```
fields: [{
    name: 'code',
    type: 'string'
}]
hasMany: [{
    name: 'modelB',
    model: 'modelB'
}]
```

Model B:

```
fields: [{
    name: 'code',
    type: 'string'
}]
```

I want to add filter to Store A (mapping with Model A) by Model B's code. For example:

```
Data: {code: 'A001', modelB: [{code: 'B001'}, {code: 'B002'}]},
      {code: 'A002', modelB: [{code: 'B001'}, {code: 'B003'}]},
      {code: 'A003', modelB: [{code: 'B002'}]}
Query value: 'B002'
Expected result: 'A001' and 'A003'
```

I tried:

```
customFilter = Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
    property: 'modelB.code',
    operation: '=',
    value: '001' // <- Model B's code
});

storeA.addFilter(customFilter);
```

It's not working. Please help!

Comment: Are you trying to filter a store of `ModelA`? If so, it doesn't really make sense. There is no `modelB.code`, because it's a collection of items. Use a custom `filterFn`.